# Using geolocation to organize back-end for iOS app similar to Uber

Tags: firebase, geolocation, backend

I am building an iOS app similar to Uber using Firebase. My issue is back end efficiency to make the app scalable.

I need to be able to organize drivers and riders by location in real time, so that when a user goes on the app to request a driver, only drivers in that particular users region will show up. So ideally my database structure would look like this:

- drivers

  - region1

    - driver1
    - driver 2
- riders

  - region1

    - rider1
    - rider2

This way when searching for drivers to display on the map view the API call is significantly more efficient than if all the drivers/riders were lumped into one big data structure.

The only way I can think to do this is to use **CLGeoCoder()** and use reverse geocoding to update the riders/drivers region in the database every time the app loads. And also monitor when a user exits or enters a new region. Is there a better way to do this? What is your best guess as to how Uber only displays drivers within a particular region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GeoFire and query locations within a certain area;

```
    var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
      center: [10.38, 2.41],
      radius: 10.5
    });

var radius = geoQuery.radius();  // radius === 10.5
```

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryradius

Comment: yes but is there anyway to filter this information in the database? My concern is efficiency of API calls. so I would need a means of organizing drivers in the database based on some sort of region, and then pulling data from that regional structure, as opposed to looking at every driver on the app and then filtering the location data